# How to Make 1st Letter of String Upperase with upper() - PYTHON

Tags: python, string, uppercase

I am trying to change the first letter of the string so that it is upper case. I know it is posible to use capitalize() or title() but I am just testing things out and wanted to know how I could do the same thing with upper(). The code I've tried comes up with error message: 'TypeError: newS must be a string on line 10'. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

```
def uppercase(string):
  string = string.replace(string[0],string[0].upper) 
  return string
print uppercase("hello")
```

Comment: `return string[0].upper() + string[1:]`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `()` while calling `upper` which is a method:

```
def uppercase(string):
  string = string.replace(string[0],string[0].upper(), 1) 
  return string

print(uppercase("hello"))
```

Also, as deceze pointed the `replace()` based approach will fail as is and you can use the optional `maxreplace` parameter to `1` to only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: That approach will fail in general for strings like `"haha"` though…

Comment: Also, it seems you are using `Python2` so I would highly recommend to switch to `python3` as `python2` is long dead.

Comment: a slice approach would work as suggested by deceze or using the optional `maxreplace` is an option to make it work with `replace` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You might do

```
def uppercase(string):
  string = string.replace(string[0],string[0].upper(),1) 
  return string
print uppercase("hello")
```

Note that there is `.upper()` i.e. method is called and `1` limit number of replacements, so `aaa` would became `Aaa` rather than `AAA`. This solution assumes `string` will never be empty `str`.